Telegram Bot API - Reason for Ban
I've developed a well-structured code for a bot, ensuring it doesn't spam by implementing message queuing to control API usage. Despite these precautions, I've been banned without understanding why.
I've reached out to Telegram's support team via email but haven't received a response. I've even lost two SIM cards trying to rectify the situation. Since I haven't received any assistance through Twitter or email, and Telegram employee doesn't have a LinkedIn presence, I'm seeking guidance here. Could someone please help me identify the necessary code changes to resolve this issue?
import os
import time
import threading
import telebot
from unsplash import download_random_image
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from queue import Queue

load_dotenv()

BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv('tg_bot_token')
OWNER_ID = int(os.getenv('tg_my_id'))
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

message_queue = Queue()  

def get_owner_username():
    try:
        owner = bot.get_chat(OWNER_ID)
        return owner.username
    except Exception as e:
        return None

def send_random_image(message, query):
    image_formats = ["regular"]
    result = download_random_image(query, image_formats)
    if result:
        photo_path = f"{query}_regular.jpg"
        with open(photo_path, "rb") as photo:
            bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'upload_photo')
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption=f"Query: {query}\nImage credits: @{get_owner_username()}", reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)  
        try:
            os.remove(photo_path)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
        bot.reply_to(message, "Oh-ho, Try with some other query word")

def process_message(message):
    if message.content_type in ['photo', 'audio', 'document', 'video', 'sticker', 'animation', 'voice', 'video_note', 'contact', 'location', 'venue', 'poll']:
        bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
        content_type = message.content_type.split('/')[0]
        bot.reply_to(message, f"I'm sorry, but I can only process text queries at the moment. {content_type.upper()} queries can't be processed.")
        return

    if message.text:
        if message.text.startswith('/'):
            if message.text.startswith('/start'):
                bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
                bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy! Ready for some image magic? Just send me a query like 'cat' or 'wildlife', and I'll fetch the best image for you in a flash! Let's go! ")
                return
            elif message.text.startswith('/help'):
                owner_info = f" Owner: @{get_owner_username()}\n"
                contact_message = "If you find any bugs or inappropriate results, feel free to reach out to me.\n\n"
                disclaimer_message = "Disclaimer: This bot simply provides images based on your query. It does not create them with some AI technology, so sometimes the results may not be appropriate.\n"
                bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
                bot.reply_to(message, owner_info + contact_message + disclaimer_message)
                return
            else:
                bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
                bot.reply_to(message, "I'm sorry, but I can't process commands. Please send me a text query word like 'cat'.")
                return
        else:
            query = message.text.lower() 
            bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
            bot.reply_to(message, "Making the magic happen...")
            send_random_image(message, query)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    message_queue.put(message)
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def owner_contact(message):
    message_queue.put(message)
    
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: True)
def handle_message(message):
    message_queue.put(message) 

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'audio', 'document', 'video', 'sticker', 'animation', 'voice', 'video_note', 'contact', 'location', 'venue', 'poll'])
def handle_non_text_message(message):
    message_queue.put(message)
    
def message_worker():
    while True:
        if not message_queue.empty():
            message = message_queue.get()  
            print(message.text , message.content_type)
            process_message(message)
            time.sleep(1)

message_thread = threading.Thread(target=message_worker)
message_thread.daemon = True
message_thread.start()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

I might have inadvertently triggered a ban by sending too many messages to the bot myself (just to test message queuing), but I'm not entirely sure. It could be because I forwarded a large number of messages or because I used the API incorrectly in my code.

What issue? If the code work as-is then there isn't much we can do.
